# Does Lepture/authlib support multiple oauth providers within single application?

Tags: oauth, authlib

Can a single instance of a Python application, which uses the lepture/authlib OAuth package, support multiple providers at once?

e.g. could I set up three individual handlers for one python web server instance that handled Google/OAuth2, Facebook/OAuth2, Twitter/OAuth1?

The reason I ask is I stumbled across this when first looking at bitly/oauth2_proxy. Turns out you can't do that (i.e. I'd have to run multiple oauth2_proxy processes and configure each one with its own unique provider).

Would have asked on lepture/authlib but they requested these types of questions are asked here instead using a tag of `Authlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check out the playground example, you can connect with

- github
- google
- facebook
- twitter

Play it on https://play.authlib.org/

The source code is at https://github.com/authlib/playground